# How do I get Powershell's Intellisense to auto-complete properties, cmdlets, parameters based on modules and Azure tenant values?

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense, azure-powershell, powershell-5.1, powershell-7.3

I'm using Powershell ISE, Powershell 5.1, and the Az module. I've got a wonderful Intellisense auto-complete setup that I can't seem to replicate in other powershell environments, so I'm wondering what I need to add to get the same behaviour. My current Intellisense can auto-complete:

1. Cmdlets based on my installed modules:
   [If I type in "Connect-" it suggests "Connect-AzAccount"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CyRoa.png)
2. Cmdlet parameters, based on my installed modules:
   [If I type in '-' after the Set-AzContext cmdlet, it lists all of that cmdlet's available parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYkmC.png)
3. Parameter values, based on my Azure tenant and current context:
   [After typing in the '-ResourceGroupName' parameter, it lists existing resource group names from my context's subscription](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTxaa.png)
4. Object properties
   [Typing in '.' after the variable lists all the members and functions of the object within](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbQCn.png)

All of these makes this environment ideal for development, but [Powershell ISE is no longer being developed and can't support any Powershell version beyond 5.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/windows-powershell/ise/introducing-the-windows-powershell-ise?view=powershell-7.3). I want to get this same capability on a fresh install of Powershell 7.3 while working in Visual Studio Code. What do I need to make this happen?

Current powershell versions:
[Current PSVersion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v25bh.png)

I've tried installing other Intellisense packages on an install of Powershell 7.3, but they're all history-based, which isn't as useful as suggestions based on modules or Azure, and my few hours of searching for module-based or azure-based Intellisense autocomplete haven't yielded anything useful yet.

I want a better understanding of what libraries and tools are powering my Intellisense suggestions, so that I can replicate this excellent Intellisense setup elsewhere.